# Can i watch for file/folder rename events?

Tags: java, jodd

Trying to implement watch file/folder events like (CREATE, DELETE, MODIFY, RENAME) with java 8  to java 11 versions for multiple platforms like windows/unix/linux with java nio package

Observed CREATE/DELETE/MODIFY works fine. Trying to sort out how can can capture rename events on file or folders.

```
            key = filePath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
             break;
        case modified:
            key = filePath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
            break;
        case deleted:
            key = filePath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
            break;
        case renamed:
            key = filePath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
             break;
         default:
            break;
```

There is nor error on rename events, its generating multiple events like delete and create, looking for a more reliable solution for this.

Comment: This is not a Jodd related question? If so, please consider removing `Jodd` tad and add e.g. `Java`

Comment: You can use this https://jpathwatch.wordpress.com/